# Angular : pass only new Data array using http

Tags: arrays, angular, leaflet, polyline

I'm try developing a flights tracker using Leaflet map API . Every certain time when there are any new coordinates point position of aircraft i displaying them on map as polyline path i have "connection" between the last and the first point as straight lines overlap with existing original polyline of flight path due using interval function to check new coordinates point position . Each time when i call `AddPAth`method to pass ' coordinates point '  i have to pass only new points to it . Otherwise i will have that "connection" between the last and the first point as straight lines overlap with existing original polyline . So my question is , what is a best way to initializing data json coordinates on the map then pass only new data to avoiding "connection" between the last and the first point as [as example here](https://ibb.co/SVqTG6f)

My code

```
export class MapTrackBeforPage implements OnInit {
    map: Map;
    poly:L.Polyline


    constructor(
        private http: HTTP,
       public zone : NgZone) {

    }


    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.getmarker().then(() => {
            this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
                interval(15000).subscribe(() => {
                  ---- Reload DATA
                    this.getmarker()
                })
            })
        })

        // In setView add latLng and zoom
        this.map = new Map('Map_id', { attributionControl: false }).setView([33, 44], 6);
        this.sourceFlightPath.addTo(this.map)
        return tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport-dark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=', {
        }).addTo(this.map);
    }

    ---- GETTING DATA --------
    async getmarker() {
        this.http.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {}, {})
            .then(data => {

                let getdata = JSON.parse(data.data)

               --------Pass Data -----
                this.AddPath(getdata)

            })
    }

------ PATH OF AIRCRAFT -----
    AddPath(path) {
        // Flight path

        for (let datas of path['trail']) {

         new L.Polyline([datas.lat,datas.lng], { color: 'red', weight: 3 }).addTo(this.map);

        }
    }
```

short data json

```
{
  "trail": [
    {
      "lat": 28.859594,
      "lng": 44.736115
    },
    {
      "lat": 28.852707,
      "lng": 44.76506
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use **RXJS** and **distinct** operator, here is an example:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { distinct } from 'rxjs/operators';

of(1, 1, 2).pipe(
  distinct(),
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // it gives you 1, 2
```

You can use start with operator **startWith** if you need it, so it can be something like this in your case:

```
this.http.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {}, {})
        .pipe(
           startWith(your_initial_value),
           map(data => data.data),
           distinct()
         )
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.AddPath(getdata)
        })
```

you can create an observable from a promise if you are using http plugin of ionic

```
observable$ = from(this._http.get(this.forecastUrl, {}, {}));
```

you can find more example here https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/distinct

Comment: where should i use ? in `AddPath` or in `getmarker`

Comment: There problem is l cant use  RXJS and distinct operator because i am using http plugin , and that plugin doesn't accept pipe and  subscribe then , catch , finally

Comment: That can't be the case considering this is an Angular app and RxJs is packaged with it.

Comment: you can create an observable from a promise using from operator

Comment: noo you can use rxjs , npm install rxjs , it's not related to angular

Comment: l cant getting data from `subscribe(data => {
           
        })` because parameter data: number

Comment: rxjs's `distinct` seems a bit overkill since support for `Set` is commonplace these days. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set